# How can I use GDB with GCOV?

Tags: gdb, gcov

I looked at this article here: http://www.linux-mag.com/id/1409/

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <stdio.h>


int main(argc, argv)

int argc;

char **argv;

{

  int x, y;

  int arraysize;

  int **array;

  if (argc != 2) {

    printf(“Usage: %s Enter arraysize value \n”,argv[0]);

    exit(-1);

  } else {

    arraysize = atoi (argv[1]);

    if (arraysize <= 0) {

      printf(“Array size must be larger than 0 \n”);

      exit(-1);

    }

  }


  array = (int **) malloc (arraysize*sizeof (int *));


  printf(“Creating an %d by %d array \n”, arraysize, arraysize);


  if (array == NULL) {

    printf(“Malloc failed for array size %d \n”, arraysize);

    exit(-1);

  }

  for (x=0; x < arraysize; x++) {

    array[x] = (int *) malloc (arraysize*sizeof (int));

    if (array[x] == NULL) {

34:      printf(“Failed malloc for array size %d \n”, arraysize);

      exit(-1);

    }

  }

  exit(0);

}
```

And the article is straightforward.  It suggests using GDB to get coverage by "jump"ing to the lines which are normally unreachable.  However, it doesn't work as described.  What I found is that if I use the "jump" command in GDB, gcov does not recognize the line as executed.  I have to actually break on the line before, and munge the array variable to force the code to recognize a malloc failure.  In general, this may or may not be as easy.  Jump seems like an easier way to get to code, but it's not working.

So there are really 2 questions here.

Why doesn't gcov recognize a gdb jump?

Why does one version of gcov/gdb recognize a jump and another does not?  How can I tell whether the 2 programs are compatible or not?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show some sample code? From what I've read, gcc's test coverage works by incrementing a counter at the beginning of a basic block. If you use the debugger to jump into the middle of a basic block, the increment instruction might be skipped.

Comment: I added the code from the web link.  If I try "jump 34" from gdb, the code exits and prints out what I expect, but GCOV does not report that line covered.  It could be the case that it skipped a beginning of a basic block, but then how did the person from the original web page get their example to work?  Somehow gdb, gcc, and/or gcov are not doing the same thing every time, but I don't know how to determine that.

Comment: I can reproduce it and will look into it.  As for why different versions of code coverage software act differently: the article you linked to is over 11 years old. Gcc and gcov may very well have changed their implementations since then.